# Evaluate and run a script with Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

I have a code that works as expected on the server that generates C# code dynamically and then runs it. To run the code I use the following:

```
string assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
MetadataReference[] references = new MetadataReference[]
{
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(RunResult).Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Console.dll")),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Runtime.dll")),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Runtime.Extensions.dll")),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Collections.dll")),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Text.Json.dll"))
};

var f =
    await CSharpScript.Create(
            code: code,
            options: ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences(references))
        .ContinueWith<Func<RunResult, bool>>("new EvaluatorClass().Run")
        .CreateDelegate()
        .Invoke();

await using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    await using (StreamWriter currentOut = new StreamWriter(ms) { AutoFlush = true })
    {
        var runResult = f(codeResult);
    }
}
```

I have written this code as part of a .NET Standard library, and I would now like to run this on the client side using Blazor WebAssembly.

When I debugged I saw that the problem is that `string assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);` returns null, and therefor it's not possible (as far as I know) to include the references that are needed by the code being executed.

Is there another way this could be achieved so it would work on Blazor?

Comment: You must understand that any WASM application fully runs at the client side, in a webbrowser. It is in a container. There's no way to access the local file system that way (that would be a great security risk).

Comment: @JHBonarius I realize that. But I would have expected that the .NET FW that is downloaded as WASM to the browser might have some overcome to such case.

Comment: I also tried having those DLLs a embedded resources and getting the MetadataReference from stream - again it worked on the server but not on WASM for unknown reason

Comment: @developer82 Any updates on this?
I want to run dynamically defined C# code (by the user) directly on his browser, I think it is pretty similar to what you are trying to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I answered this in another, similar but not identical question. They were using CSharpCompilation and you are using CSharpScript. Both want a bunch of MetadataReferences but, as you found, Assembly.Location in Blazor WASM is null.

So instead of:

```cs
MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Location)
```

In Blazor WASM use:

```cs
MetadataReference.CreateFromImage([Assembly Bytes])
```

In Blazor WASM you can get an Assembly MetadataReference by using HttpClient to get the Assembly bytes and MetadataReference.CreateFromImage to create the MetadataReference object from them. Example working method below.

```cs
async Task<MetadataReference?> GetAssemblyMetadataReference(Assembly assembly)
{
    MetadataReference? ret = null;
    var assemblyName = assembly.GetName().Name;
    var assemblyUrl = $"./_framework/{assemblyName}.dll";
    try
    {
        var tmp = await _httpClient.GetAsync(assemblyUrl);
        if (tmp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var bytes = await tmp.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            ret = MetadataReference.CreateFromImage(bytes);
        }
    }
    catch { }
    return ret;
}
```

My related answer to a similar question.
[How do I create a CSharpCompilation using Roslyn in Blazor WebAssembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74351536/how-do-i-create-a-csharpcompilation-using-roslyn-in-blazor-webassembly/75378471#75378471)

My full example repo https://github.com/LostBeard/BlazorWASMScriptLoader

### Update for .Net 8:

In .Net 8 Blazor WASM creates .wasm files instead of .dll files. This is the Webcil format and it "addresses environments that block clients from downloading and executing DLLs". The problem is .wasm files do not contain the MetadataReference data like the .dll files did. A workaround is to switch back to using .dlls by using the `<WasmEnableWebcil>false</WasmEnableWebcil>` tag in the project .csproj file.

Webcil Reference:
[Web-friendly Webcil packaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-8.0?view=aspnetcore-8.0#web-friendly-webcil-packaging)

Comment: This works very well, would it be possible to store the assembly bytes in a local cache, to avoid loading them every time from the server?

Comment: Of course. There a lot of ways to cache that data. Some already happen for you..  If your app is a PWA they bytes will already be stored in your local cache. If you are not, the requests to the server for the Dlls will likely result in a server response of 304 (Not modified) which means your app will not actually download the bytes again from the server and instead use the browser's cache. If you check my demo repo linked in my answer you I use basic caching of the MetadataReference data using a Dictionary.

Comment: I saw your repository, I'm going to test it, in the initial approach the time to compile and execute was long, I'm going to test it, thanks for the help.  

Answer (score 0):

could you try inferring references, instead of loading files?

```cs
var scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default;
scriptOptions = scriptOptions.AddReferences(
    typeof(System.Object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly,
    typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).GetTypeInfo().Assembly,
    /* don't know where `RunResult` comes from, add it yourself */);
scriptOptions = scriptOptions.AddImports(
    "System.Console",
    "System.Runtime",
    "System.Runtime.Extensions",
    "System.Collections",
    "System.Text.Json");

var f =
    await CSharpScript.Create(
            code: code,
            options: scriptOptions)
        [...etc...]
```

edit: i've edited in the `scriptOptions = scriptOptions.[...]` notation. I don't get it, but it seems to be the way people do it online... It seems wrong to me.
edit2: Ok, found it [`ScriptOption`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Scripting/Core/ScriptOptions.cs) seems to use immutable data structures internally. So the calls will (likely) return a new object.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment. I got the following exception: `System.NotSupportedException: Can't create a metadata reference to an assembly without location.` - A previous attempt of mine to have the DLLs as embedded resources and loading the metadata from stream yield the same error. Guess it's not something that would be possible with Blazor WASM